# How can I add a breakline on PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to make a breakline on PHPMailer on the message of my email.

Here is how I do it:

```
$message  = '';
$message .= 'Line 1' . "\r\n";
$message .= 'Line 2' . "\r\n";
```

And I add it on PHPMailer as follows:

```
$mail->Body = $message;
```

where `$mail` is the instance of PHPMailer but when I send the email the message does not respect any breakline.

How can I add a breakline on PHPMailer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `<br>` since the email is sent in HTML.

Comment: I've added it as an answer! :) Glad it worked for ya ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the email is sent in HTML, your `\r\n` won't do anything.

You could use `<br>` instead.

```
$message  = '';
$message .= 'Line 1' . "<br>";
$message .= 'Line 2' . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$message  = '';
$message .= 'Line 1' . "<br>";
$message .= 'Line 2' . "<br>";
```

if you use  `'<br>'` 
it may not work

Answer (score 0):

I guess my first question would be are you sending text or html?  If html then I would build it just like I would a form..

```
$message = '';
$message .= '<p>some fantastic question</p>';
$message .= '<p>another fantastic question</p>';
```